# How to use variable in FROM clause in SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a query that will select all data on the table. The query will select to the table base on the variable that I will pass on the stored procedure.

Here in my example. If I execute `example_sp table1` it will select in `table1`. Same thing if I use `example_table table2`, it should select`table2`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE example_sp
    @type varchar(10), -- value will be `table1` or `table2`
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM @type
END
```

Comment: If you are going to pass in a table name like this you should use the sysname datatype instead of varchar(10). And follow the example that Gordon posted below making sure you use QUOTENAME as he did in his fine example. That will greatly help reduce the risk of sql injection.

Answer (score 5):

A slightly different version of what Gordon has suggested.....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE example_sp
    @TableName SYSNAME   --<-- Use appropriate data type for sql server objects
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  Declare @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @Sql = N' SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)

  Exec sp_executesql @Sql
END
```

Answer (score 4):

You need dynamic SQL to pass in identifiers such as table names and column names:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE example_sp (
    @tablename varchar(10) -- value will be `table1` or `table2`
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = 'SELECT t.* FROM @tablename t';

    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@tablename', QUOTENAME(@tablename));

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END;
```

Comment: Why not do the table name in a single statement instead of two?

Comment: Just curious...  why the replace and not a simple concat ?

Comment: execute example_sp(''';DROP TABLE STUDENTS;')

Comment: @Stavr00 the QUOTENAME greatly minimizes the risk of sql injection here. Plus your example won't fit in the varchar(10) either. :)

Comment: @Stavr00  "Little Bobby Tables" approves this message!

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . I always use `replace()` for this sort of thing.  I've found that the code is much simpler to read and maintain (although I agree that in this very simple case, there isn't much difference).

Answer (score 0):

Your SP will have to return 2 result sets, one being empty. Just put both `SELECT` statements, including `WHERE @type = 'table1'`

It's even better if the result sets match, in which case you can simply merge them with `UNION`